# How does camera.getPicture works in android using apache cordova?

Tags: android, apache, cordova, winjs

Using apache cordova plugin, I am able to open the camera function but when I take picture, application gets restarting..

```
navigator.camera.getPicture( cameraSuccess, cameraError, cameraOptions );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolved it...

we need to add below two lines in `config.xml.`

```
<preference name="KeepRunning" value="true" />
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

i also had a same problem.but, finally i get the solution for camera plugin.
and my code is below.

```
  $(document).on('click','.capture_photo',function(){
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
          quality : 75,
          destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
          sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
          encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
          popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
          saveToPhotoAlbum: false 
        });
    }); 
// to call the success function of capture image(onPhotoDataSuccess)
     function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) { 
      sessionStorage.setItem("img_api",imageData);
      $('#captureimg').attr('src','data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData);
        App.show_toast("Profile image updated successfully!");
    }
```

Hope, it will usefull

Comment: This seems to be correct, just remember to add an onFail function too, even if is something like:
function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

Comment: @epergo  ya,i forget to add onFail.

Comment: @san It works but we need to add two more lines in config.xml <preference name="KeepRunning" value="true" />
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />